# Random points inside polygon QGIS: what is the unit of minimum distance?

Tags: qgis, point, random

What is the unit of "minimum distance" in the "Random points inside polygon" function in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in map units of the spatial reference system of the polygon. I.e. if you are using a system using meters, for example UTM, then the unit is meters. If the polygon is unprojected, e.g. using WGS84, then the unit is decimal degrees.